# First argument of sys.path.insert in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Some examples show

```
sys.path.insert(0, "path/to/whatever")
```

and other examples show

```
sys.path.insert(1, "path/to/whatever").
```

But I could not find any information of regarding the effect of using 0 as opposed to 1 and vice versa, for the first input argument of the insert() function.

**Where can I find official documentation regarding this?**

**Also what is the difference between the two?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) is a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange), and so, of course, supports all `list` methods with their exact semantics.

But for `sys.path` specifically, element 0 is the path containing the script, and so using index 1 causes Python to search that path first and then the inserted path, versus the other way around when inserted at index 0.

Comment: At the time you wrote this, I was an intern dev. and I didn't fully understand your answer...now 4 years later I happened to come by this again and I finally understand the explanation. Thank you mate.